# Kafka Buffer Size And Time Interval

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka keeps data in Buffer as per buffer.memory (32 MB in my case). Does kafka writes record to topic once it reaches to 32 MB limit or is there any time associated with it as well ?

Answer (score 4):

From the Kafka docs `buffer.memory` is only the property to specify the limit of buffer for a producer to use. But since setting this property producer will not make the producer wait until the buffer gets full for sending records into the server.

**[buffer.memory](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)**

> **The total bytes of memory the producer can use to buffer records waiting to be sent to the server.** If records are sent faster than they can be delivered to the server the producer will block for max.block.ms after which it will throw an exception.

> This setting should correspond roughly to the total memory the producer will use, but is not a hard bound since not all memory the producer uses is used for buffering. Some additional memory will be used for compression (if compression is enabled) as well as for maintaining in-flight requests.

If you want the producer to wait until the batch some records in buffer gets, you can use `linger.ms` property to make the producer wait. But as far as my knowledge there is no strict way to keep producer to wait and send records only if the buffer is full

**[KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)**

> **By default a buffer is available to send immediately even if there is additional unused space in the buffer.** However, if you want to reduce the number of requests you can set linger.ms to something greater than 0. This will instruct the producer to wait up to that number of milliseconds before sending a request in hope that more records will arrive to fill up the same batch.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Then what are log.flush.interval.messages and log.flush.interval.ms ? And also why I cannot see __consumer_offset topic even though I successfully read the data in my consumer ?

Comment: Please don't ask question in comments and that should be different question with more information @AbhinavKumar